# SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file() failed

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl

I'm writing a client application on Windows that establishes an SSL connection to a server, and the server requests client certificate for authentication. The server provides me a .pfx file, then I use openssl command line tool to get the certificate and the private key like this:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in filename.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out cert.pem
openssl pkcs12 -in filename.pfx -nocerts -out key.pem
```

after that, I try to load the certificate and the private key with functions from openssl as below, but `SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file()` always failed, the error message is "`error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line`", I can't figure it out why, can anyone give me some enlightenment? 
Here is the code.

```
#include "openssl/ssl.h"
#include "openssl/err.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

int InitClientCtx()
{
    OpenSSL_add_ssl_algorithms();

    SSL_CTX* m_pClientCtx;
    m_pClientCtx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_method());

    if(!m_pClientCtx)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    ::SSL_CTX_set_options(m_pClientCtx, SSL_OP_ALL);  //for well-known bugs

    int nRet = 0;

    std::string sCertFilePath = "C:\\cert.pem";

    nRet = SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file(m_pClientCtx, sCertFilePath.c_str());

    std::string sKeyPassWord = "123456";

    SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb_userdata(m_pClientCtx, (void*)(sKeyPassWord.c_str()));

    std::string sKeyFilePath = "C:\\key.pem";

    // this method returned 0, which means it failed.
    nRet = SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(m_pClientCtx, sKeyFilePath.c_str(), SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);

    SSL_load_error_strings();
    unsigned long n = ERR_get_error();
    char buf[1024];
    printf("%s\n", ERR_error_string(n, buf));

    nRet = SSL_CTX_check_private_key(m_pClientCtx);
    if (nRet <= 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    /*std::string sCACertFilePath;

    nRet = SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(m_pClientCtx, sCACertFilePath.c_str(), NULL);*/

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    InitClientCtx();
    return 0;
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've solved this problem myself. I generated the key.pem using OpenSSL for Windows, when the CMD prompts me to type in the pass phrase, **I just typed a Enter since I needn't a pass phrase, but the key.pem was invalid(neither `BEGIN` nor `END` markers). When I generate the private key in Linux, the terminal prompts I must type a pass phrase and I do.** Then I remove the key pass phrase using this command:

`openssl rsa -in key.pem -out newkey.pem`

After that, I open the key.pem in a text editor, it starts off with `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` and end up with `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`. And SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file() just works fine!

Comment: Very useful trick for removing the password of a key file. _Add to toolbox_.

Answer (score 15):

In my case the error was because the PEM file did not contain both a key and a certificate.

Make sure your file contains both sections:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- jhajk838383jks.....
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- yoe55wjcxnshre.....
-----END CERTIFICATE KEY-----
```

I catenated `.key` and `.crt` files I already had in my Apache configuration to make a `.pem` file.

The 'no start line' error is certainly misleading as you can have a perfectly good "BEGIN" line in your PEM file and still get the error.

Answer (score 5):

The error `error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line` is because in both the cert.pem as well as key.pem, don't start off with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and `-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----`.

If you open up your cert.pem and key.pem in a text editor and yank off whatever is there before the `BEGIN` markers, you should be good.

When you create a certificate and a key pair using **Certificate Signing Request**, you won't get this additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Under openssl directory demo/openssl there is a client example.

Change:

```
meth = SSLv2_client_method();
```

in your case to:

```
meth = SSLv23_client_method();
```

Try this example and see where it fails.

Are you sure that the key password is 123456 ?

Comment: I don't think it matters. The SSLv2 vs SSLv23 distinction matters **only** when you make a connection. In the above case, the error is issued before even a connection is made.

Comment: @Cyril No. it's the passphrase that matters.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in NGINX while installing the SSL certificate and I resolved using the following step:

- Go to the folder where you have your certificate and pem files
- Open your `ca-bundle.crt` file and copy everything, `sudo nano your fileName` select all and copy. the file looks like

> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIIE0DCCA7igAwIBAgIBBzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADCBgzELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMx
>   EDAOBgNVBAgTB0FyaXpvbmExEzARBgNVBAcTClNjb3R0c2RhbGUxGjAYBgNVBAoT
>   ..........
>
> -----END CERTIFICATE-----
>
> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIIEfTCCA2WgAwIBAgIDG+cVMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMGMxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVT
>   MSEwHwYDVQQKExhUaGUgR28gRGFkZHkgR3JvdXAsIEluYy4xMTAvBgNVBAsTKEdv
>   ..........
>
> -----END CERTIFICATE-----
>
> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIIEADCCAuigAwIBAgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBjMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEh
>   MB8GA1UEChMYVGhlIEdvIERhZGR5IEdyb3VwLCBJbmMuMTEwLwYDVQQLEyhHbyBE
>   ..........
>   -----END CERTIFICATE-----

- Open your pem file using `sudo nano your fileName.pem`
- You will see some code like

> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIIGLzCCBRegAwIBAgIIWI4ndTQi3MwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwgbQxCzAJBgNV
>   MAAwHQYDVR0lBBYwFAYIKwYBBQUHAwEGCCsGAQUFBwMCMA4GA1UdDwEB/wQEAwIF
>   oDA4BgNVHR8EMTAvMC2gK6AphidodHRwOi8vY3JsLmdvZGFkZHkuY29tL2dkaWcy
>
> -----END CERTIFICATE-----

- After `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` paste all the code copied from `ca-bundle.crt` file and save it
- Restart your `Nginx` server using following command `sudo service nginx restart`

The above steps worked for me in my Nginx and SSL configuration